# How to exclude peer rows of the current row from the window frame?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Schema**

```sql
create table items(id integer, number integer);
insert into items values
  (1, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 2),
  (4, 2),
  (5, 3);
```

**Query**

```sql
select id, string_agg(id::text, ',') over (order by number)
from items;
```

The above query produces the following:

```
id | string_agg
---+-----------
1  | 1,2
2  | 1,2
3  | 1,2,3,4
4  | 1,2,3,4
5  | 1,2,3,4,5
```

however I do not want the window frame to include any peer rows of the current row, i.e.:

```
id | string_agg
---+-----------
1  | 
2  | 
3  | 1,2
4  | 1,2
5  | 1,2,3,4
```

I need something like:

```
range between unbounded preceding and (first peer row - 1)
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't fully understand your logic.  Can you explain clearly the logic behind your expected output?

Comment: The default window frame has a frame_end of `CURRENT ROW`. According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html), `frame_end of CURRENT ROW means the frame ends with the last equivalent ORDER BY peer` but I want it to be `frame ends with row prior to the first equivalent ORDER BY peer`. I want the window frame to include only rows with `number` less than `number` of the current row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of different ways to approach this:

- Use arrays and do some array manipulations.
- Calculate the values and then separately join the final result in.
- Weird data manipulation.

This goes for the third option.  It generates the list and then removes the values for the current "group":

```
select id,
       trim(replace(string_agg(id::text, ',') over (order by number),
                    string_agg(id::text, ',') over (partition by number),
                    ''
                   ), ','
           )
from items i;
```

This makes the following two assumptions:

- The ids are unique.
- The only repeated numbers are those next to each other.

[Here](http://rextester.com/JPCS43033) is a rextester.